# How to solve these errors in Android studio

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

[These errors are coming in Packages or libraries
unable to solve these error please help me how to solve these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qst3p.png)

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: @Mahi post your xml code